# What ios method references "login through UIWebview and redirects me to another view controller"?

Tags: iphone, ios, django, authentication, webview

I'm on developing iphone app that uses backend web service(django).

To login the web service, I made a webview (loginviewcontroller) contains (and shows) login web page(html).

After I submit username & password, django web site redirects me to a kind of dashboard page.(if login succeeded)

I only want to login to web service, not redirecting me another webpage.

What method reference I can count on this case?

I want it like to after login success, redirects me to another view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make custom logic for this.

you can check for login in webview delegate method that webview didfinished loading.

there you can set condition for url.

if you get desired url after login then move next tab.

Comment: And I found great answer for me after googling my own question haha...and of course thank you! http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/18701